# Regex for blacklist and whitelist words

Tags: regex, blacklist

I'm trying to set up regex for a blacklist and whitelist, flagging blacklisted words and ignoring whitelisted words.  Here are the rules:

1. I want to see if a word or phrase on the blacklist exists in the input string.
2. The blacklist words should be matched regardless of where they appear (full word or as substring).
3. The whitelist words (i.e. words that are known to be okay even though they contain blacklisted words) are not to be matched if they are full words only.

Blacklist words I want to search for and match if found:  BUNNY, GARDEN, HOLE

Whitelist words that are clean and can be ignored even though they contain blacklisted words:  WHOLE, GARDENER

I made the following regex using negative lookbehind:
`(BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)(?<!\bWHOLE\b|\bGARDENER\b)`

My silly example string:
*This whole hole is a wholey mistake in the gardener agardener.*

I would expect only the following be matched:
"hole"
"wholey"
"agardener"

It mostly works, since "whole" doesn't match but "wholey" does and "agardener" is also a match. However, "gardener" matches even though it's in the whitelist.  What am I missing?

Comment: `(\bBUNNY\b|\bGARDEN\b|\bHOLE\b)`?

Comment: First of all, you need to clarify what you mean by a "blacklist".  By definition, if it's not on your whitelist, it's not going to match.  So what's the difference between a word that's on your blacklist and a word that's on neither list?  And, if we can just ignore the blacklist, does something like this suit your purposes? `\b(BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)\b`

Comment: Thanks for the input @Charlie Armstrong. I updated the question. I'm trying to determine if a blacklisted word exists in the input string, but if the blacklisted word is part of a whitelisted word, to ignore that match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\w*(?:BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)\w*\b(?<!\bWHOLE|\bGARDENER)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SopvN/2).

A variation without a lookbehind, but with a lookahead:

```php
\b(?!(?:WHOLE|GARDENER)\b)\w*(?:BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)\w*\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SopvN/3).

*Details*:

- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `(?:BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)` - one of the required word parts
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bWHOLE|\bGARDENER)`  - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there whole word situated on the left is `WHOLE` or `GARDENER`.

The `\b(?!(?:WHOLE|GARDENER)\b)\w*(?:BUNNY|GARDEN|HOLE)\w*\b` matches a word boundary first, then fails the match if the next chars are a `WHOLE` or `GARDENER` whole words and then matches a word with `BUNNY`, `GARDEN` or `HOLE` substring in it.

Replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` or `\p{L}` (or `[[:alpha:]]`) if supported and you need to only match letter words.